# Как импортировать нужные библиотеки в готовый jar файл?

Tags: java, netbeans

Делаю программу. Программа работает со сторонними библиотеками. Естественно запуск программы на другом компе не работает из-за отсутствия этих библиотек. Как можно "таскать" библиотеки вместе с jar файлом? NetBeans

Comment: Либо указать в манифесте classpath со списком зависимостей и предоставлять пользователю свой jar вместе с jar'ами зависимостей, либо создать fat jar, включающий все зависимости в себя.

Comment: В принципе то что нужно, где можно прочитать про первый или второй вариант? Суть в том, что мне нужно, чтобы использованные библиотеки были всегда с моим jar ником вместе.

Comment: http://arunasujith.blogspot.ru/2011/08/how-to-build-fat-jar-using-netbeans.html

Answer (score 1):

Например, таскать зависимости с собой. Т.е. положить их в папку lib и прописать относительный путь к ним в манифесте.

Answer (score 0):

Можно использовать Maven, у него есть удобный плагин для интегрирования всех подключенных библиотек в jar.

**maven-shade-plugin**
Подключается так:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.0</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>shade</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <transformers>
                    <transformer implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ManifestResourceTransformer">
                        <mainClass>package.MainClass</mainClass>
                    </transformer>
                </transformers>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```